# Mysql query to set field to first non null, non zero value from two other fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table `schools` in a MySQL db, which has columns `number_of_pupils`, `pupil_capacity` and `pupil_numbers_or_capacity` (all integer fields).

I want to set the `pupil_numbers_or_capacity` field according to the following rules:

- if number_of_pupils is not null, and is greater than zero, use that.
- **otherwise**, if pupil_capacity is not null, and is greater than zero, use that.
- if neither of the above, don't update it.

Can I do this in a single update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE schools t
   SET t.pupil_numbers_or_capacity = CASE WHEN number_of_pupils > 0
                                          THEN number_of_pupils
                                          ELSE pupil_capacity END
 WHERE t.number_of_pupils > 0
    OR t.pupil_capacity > 0
```

Comment: The key here is that a `>` test automatically precludes nulls - I forgot that.